# How to run a "Make Table" Query with a parameter in Access 2002 from Excel 2003 VBA

Tags: ms-access, excel-2003

I have looked around a bit and found what I believe could be the solution but this is not working :-(

I have never used this method and really don't know where I am going wrong, maybe I need to use another method?
Either way the SQL works fine in Access.
Could someone please have a look at it and point me in the right direction?
Thanks for your time and consideration.

Nick

```
    Dim cmd As New ADODB.Command
    Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim prm As ADODB.Parameter
    Dim strConn As String

    Set cmd = New ADODB.Command

    KdNr=12564 'Parameter to be passed (set here as dummy)

    cmd.ActiveConnection = CurrentProject.Connection
    cmd.CommandText = "CREATE PROCEDURE procUmsatz " & _
    "(CustNo long) " & _
    "AS SELECT dbo_STATISTIKVK.KUNDE, Sum(dbo_STATISTIKVK.WERTEK) AS WE_Gesamt, Sum(dbo_STATISTIKVK.WERTVK) AS Umsatz_Gesamt, ([Umsatz_Gesamt]-[WE_Gesamt])/[Umsatz_Gesamt] AS Spanne_PC_Gesamt, [Umsatz_Gesamt]-[WE_Gesamt] AS Spanne_EUR_Gesamt, Year([BELEGDAT]) AS Year_, dbo_STATISTIKVK.ARTIKEL INTO tbl_Excel_Umsatz " & _
    "FROM dbo_STATISTIKVK " & _
    "WHERE (((dbo_STATISTIKVK.MENGE)>0) AND ((dbo_STATISTIKVK.BELEGDAT)>#1/1/2010#)) " & _
    "GROUP BY dbo_STATISTIKVK.KUNDE, Year([BELEGDAT]), dbo_STATISTIKVK.ARTIKEL " & _
    "HAVING (((dbo_STATISTIKVK.KUNDE)= [CustNo]) AND ((Sum(dbo_STATISTIKVK.WERTVK))>0) AND ((dbo_STATISTIKVK.ARTIKEL)<>""VERSAND"" And (dbo_STATISTIKVK.ARTIKEL)<>""99"" And (dbo_STATISTIKVK.ARTIKEL)<>""MAN"" And (dbo_STATISTIKVK.ARTIKEL)<>""Manuell"")) " & _
    "ORDER BY Year([BELEGDAT])"

    cmd.Execute

    '--------------------------------------------------------------------------

    strConn = "Provider = Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
    "Data Source=\\STATION\PasstProReloaded\Excel.mdb"

    Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
    conn.Open strConn

    Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
    cmd.CommandText = "procUmsatz"
    cmd.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
    cmd.ActiveConnection = conn

    Set prm = cmd.CreateParameter("CustNo", adInteger, adParamInput)
    cmd.Parameters.Append prm
    cmd.Parameters("CustNo").Value = KdNr

    'Execute the Stored Procedure
    cmd.Execute

    'Close the connection
    conn.Close
```

Comment: Where is your code failing? Is the top half run in MS Access and the bottom half run in Excel?

Comment: Hi Remou, its all in Excel. It doesn't like the SQL Statement at the moment. There may be more wrong with it though. I really have no experience with this method at all. I have just reverse-engineered snippets out the Net. Maybe there is a simpler way to run this?

Comment: Is that an SQL Server query? Because it looks like it and in that case I need to revise my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try moving that around a bit, Excel is unlikely to have an active connection:

```
strConn = "Provider = Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
"Data Source=\\STATION\PasstProReloaded\Excel.mdb"

Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
conn.Open strConn

cmd.ActiveConnection = strConn
cmd.CommandText = "CREATE PROCEDURE procUmsatz " & _
"(CustNo long) " & _
"AS SELECT dbo_STATISTIKVK.KUNDE, Sum(dbo_STATISTIKVK.WERTEK) AS WE_Gesamt, Sum(dbo_STATISTIKVK.WERTVK) AS Umsatz_Gesamt, ([Umsatz_Gesamt]-[WE_Gesamt])/[Umsatz_Gesamt] AS Spanne_PC_Gesamt, [Umsatz_Gesamt]-[WE_Gesamt] AS Spanne_EUR_Gesamt, Year([BELEGDAT]) AS Year_, dbo_STATISTIKVK.ARTIKEL INTO tbl_Excel_Umsatz " & _
"FROM dbo_STATISTIKVK " & _
"WHERE (((dbo_STATISTIKVK.MENGE)>0) AND ((dbo_STATISTIKVK.BELEGDAT)>#1/1/2010#)) " & _
"GROUP BY dbo_STATISTIKVK.KUNDE, Year([BELEGDAT]), dbo_STATISTIKVK.ARTIKEL " & _
"HAVING (((dbo_STATISTIKVK.KUNDE)= [CustNo]) AND ((Sum(dbo_STATISTIKVK.WERTVK))>0) AND ((dbo_STATISTIKVK.ARTIKEL)<>""VERSAND"" And (dbo_STATISTIKVK.ARTIKEL)<>""99"" And (dbo_STATISTIKVK.ARTIKEL)<>""MAN"" And (dbo_STATISTIKVK.ARTIKEL)<>""Manuell"")) " & _
"ORDER BY Year([BELEGDAT])"

cmd.Execute
```

EDIT re comments

```
KdNr=12564 'Parameter to be passed (set here as dummy)

strConn = "Provider = Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
"Data Source=\\STATION\PasstProReloaded\Excel.mdb"

Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
conn.Open strConn

cmd.ActiveConnection = strConn

cmd.CommandText = "SELECT dbo_STATISTIKVK.KUNDE, Sum(dbo_STATISTIKVK.WERTEK) AS WE_Gesamt, Sum(dbo_STATISTIKVK.WERTVK) AS Umsatz_Gesamt, ([Umsatz_Gesamt]-[WE_Gesamt])/[Umsatz_Gesamt] AS Spanne_PC_Gesamt, [Umsatz_Gesamt]-[WE_Gesamt] AS Spanne_EUR_Gesamt, Year([BELEGDAT]) AS Year_, dbo_STATISTIKVK.ARTIKEL INTO tbl_Excel_Umsatz " & _
"FROM dbo_STATISTIKVK " & _
"WHERE (((dbo_STATISTIKVK.MENGE)>0) AND ((dbo_STATISTIKVK.BELEGDAT)>#1/1/2010#)) " & _
"GROUP BY dbo_STATISTIKVK.KUNDE, Year([BELEGDAT]), dbo_STATISTIKVK.ARTIKEL " & _
"HAVING (((dbo_STATISTIKVK.KUNDE)= [CustNo]) AND ((Sum(dbo_STATISTIKVK.WERTVK))>0) AND ((dbo_STATISTIKVK.ARTIKEL)<>'VERSAND' And (dbo_STATISTIKVK.ARTIKEL)<>'99' And (dbo_STATISTIKVK.ARTIKEL)<>'MAN' And (dbo_STATISTIKVK.ARTIKEL)<>'Manuell')) "

Set prm = cmd.CreateParameter("CustNo", adInteger, adParamInput)
cmd.Parameters.Append prm
cmd.Parameters("CustNo").Value = KdNr

''Debugging
Debug.Print cmd.CommandText
Stop
''End of debugging
cmd.Execute
```

Alternative, where the query already exists as procUmsatz in MS Access

```
strConn = "Provider = Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
"Data Source=\\STATION\PasstProReloaded\Excel.mdb"

Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
conn.Open strConn

Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
cmd.ActiveConnection = strConn
cmd.CommandText = "procUmsatz"
cmd.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
cmd.ActiveConnection = conn

Set prm = cmd.CreateParameter("CustNo", adInteger, adParamInput)
cmd.Parameters.Append prm
cmd.Parameters("CustNo").Value = KdNr

'Execute the Stored Procedure
cmd.Execute
```

Comment: Ok, did that, it's now producing a -2147217900 error at the cmd.execute after the SQL Statement

Comment: After which SQL statement? BTW, the advantage of a stored procedure is that it is stored. Create the procedure in MS Access, make sure it works, then just reference it in Excel, this would eliminate the code before the dashed line. In Access, a stored procedure is really just a parameter query.

Comment: OK, sorry, the error is here: "ORDER BY Year([BELEGDAT])" >cmd.execute. As I said before, I am out of my depth here, I have a bunch of queries in Access being called by Excel. It worked fine until the need for a "Make Table" Query arose. I had been using Querydef quick & simple which appears not to work in this instance. The Query above already exists in the DB.

Comment: Try the above. You will see I have put in a small debugging section that will print the SQL to the immediate window (ctrl+G). You can view the sql and test it in MS Access.

Comment: Once it is working, you will want to add in a few bits and pieces to see how many records are created (recordsaffected) and so forth.

Comment: Great!! I, with your help, got it to work! The problem was that the table already existed but I have solved that too. Remou - thanks for your input :-))